# Rails full error message without attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I cannot get rid of the attribute in the error message. (I wonder why this isn't the default behaviour)

**Controller**

```
if @item.save
      ...
 else
   format.html { redirect_to [@profile, :items], alert: @item.errors.full_messages}
end
```

**it.yml**

```
 it:
  errors:
    format: "%{message}"
```

**View.html**

```
<% if alert %>
    <% Array.wrap(alert).each do |msg| %>
        <%=msg%>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But i get this output

ATTRIBUTE NAME my custom message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `messages` instead of `full_messages`:

```
@item.errors.messages.values.flatten
```

As `messages` returns a hash, where the key shows what's the validation error, you can simply get and flatten all values.

```
{ :email=>["Another record exists with this email."], ... } # for example
```

Comment: Yes, it works. But I cannot explain why the it.errors.format doesn't work.

Comment: It's the expected behaviour as you can see in the source code of `full_messages` (https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Errors/full_messages) and `full_message` (https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Errors/full_message) methods. `full_message` returns a string concatenation of the attribute with the message

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the feature to allow overriding the error message format, as it is turned off by default.

in `config/application.rb`

```rb
config.active_model.i18n_customize_full_message = true
```

Then you can customise format either globally, at the model level, or the attribute level.
e.g.

```yaml
it:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        model_name:
          attributes:
            attribute_name:
              not_a_number: "My custom message"
              greater_than: "My custom message"
              format: "%{message}"
```

(replace `model_name` and `attribute_name` and the validation keys as appropriate).

The `i18n-debug` gem is also handy for debugging i18n issues.